# ploting geom_points labels over raster data ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, raster, r-sp

I'm currently creating raster maps with `ggplot2`, I have some points that I want the names to be seen on the map. For this I'm using `geom_point()` but I can't figure out how to show the labels for each point. The code I'm using and the resulting map are bellow

```
library(gstat)
library(sp)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(rgdal)
library(sf)
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)
library(ggthemes)

# converting raster to df for ggplot
test_spdf <- as(raster, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame")
test_df <- as.data.frame(test_spdf)
colnames(test_df) <- c("value", "x", "y") 

# creates my points df from a spatialpointdataframe
dpts <- data.frame(estacoes@coords)
dpts$nomes <- estacoes$abrv
colnames(dpts) <- c("x", "y", "nome")

spf <- pauf # is my spatial polygons object

test <- ggplot() +  
  geom_tile(data=test_df, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=value), alpha=0.8) + 
  geom_polygon(data=spf, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), 
               fill=NA, size=0.25) +
  scale_fill_viridis(option="D") +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_map() +
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  theme(legend.key.width=unit(2, "cm")) + 
  geom_point(data=dpts, aes(x=x, y=y), size=3, shape=4)
```

[image]

Comment: See `geom_label()` or `geom_text()`

Answer (score 0):

just changed the geom_point() function with this and got exactly what i wanted. `geom_label_repel` is from `ggrepel` package

```
+ geom_label_repel(data= dpts, aes(x=x,y=y,label=nome),
                 box.padding   = 0.35, 
                 point.padding = 0.5,
                 segment.color = 'grey50')
```

[image]